# NXP QN9021 (ARM Cortex M0) programmer

Tags: arm, programmer, cortex-m0

I have made a small breakout board with the [QN9021](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/more-processors/application-specific-mcus-mpus/bluetooth-low-energy-ble/ultra-low-power-ble-system-on-chip-solution:QN9021) SOC (BLE + ARM Cortex M0). I am having trouble flashing the code into this device. Assuming that this device is wired properly and working fine, how do I program it?
None of the cheap OpenOCD debuggers seem to support it! and the commercial (JLink/ULink) are too costly for me.
Can I still use the unsupported debuggers somehow (mayne by manually adding the memory location map)? If so kindly tell me how to do so?

Comment: openocd knows how to speak swd, what did you try?  stlink?  you can get a nucleo board for about $10 (cheaper than the dedicated stlink dongle), remove the jumpers and use it as an SWD/openocd debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QBlue ISP programmer using UART communication. You need a USB serial TTL convertor with 3.3V.

Comment: UM10995 from the NXP website describes the UART bootloader interface, you can use an existing one or write your own (host-loader) program.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [LPC Link2](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/lpc-cortex-m-mcus/lpc-low-power-cortex-m4-mcus/lpc4300-cortex-m4-m0-mcus/lpc-link2:OM13054)? It's only about $20.